# Tags aggregation in Elastic Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregate, aggregation

I am having some problem trying to find out how is the aggregation of the number of documents per tags are working.

My mapping looks like:

```
"properties" => array(
                    "name" => array(
                        "type" => "string"
                    ),
                    "location" => array(
                        "type" => "geo_point"
                    ),
                    "city" => array(
                        "type" => "string",
                    ),
                    "tags" => array(
                        "type" => "integer"
                    ))
```

`tags` contains an array of integers. I tried:

```
"aggs": {
        "tags_count": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tags"
            }

}
```

I think because it is an array of Tags, it doesn't take individually each Tag and looks through the result query and tries to aggregate those tags existing in the result.

Some hits would be greatly appreciated!

Search Result:

```
"hits":
    {
        "total": 345,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits":
        [
            {
                "_index": "offers",
                "_type": "offer",
                "_id": "13648190",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source":
                {
                    "tags":
                    [
                        "28",
                        "42",
                        "44",
                        "112",
                        "136",
                        "176",
                        "180",
                        "816",
                        "920",
                        "1491"
                    ],

                    "location":
                    {
                        "lon": "8.41450977",
                        "lat": "48.45690918"
                    },

                    "name": "Schwarzwald - 4* Wellnesshotel Palmenwald",
                }
            },
```

Aggregation looks like:

```
"aggregations":
    {
        "tags_count":
        {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 3034,
            "buckets":
            [
                {
                    "key": 1000,
                    "doc_count": 152
                },
                {
                    "key": 44,
                    "doc_count": 138
                },
                {
                    "key": 769,
                    "doc_count": 124
                },
                {
                    "key": 797,
                    "doc_count": 115
                },
                {
                    "key": 784,
                    "doc_count": 105
                },
                {
                    "key": 782,
                    "doc_count": 103
                },
                {
                    "key": 180,
                    "doc_count": 96
                },
                {
                    "key": 1038,
                    "doc_count": 87
                },
                {
                    "key": 999,
                    "doc_count": 57
                },
                {
                    "key": 42,
                    "doc_count": 53
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Problem is in the aggregation it does not include all the tags found in documents "tags". The whole search should have at least 300-400 tags and the count seems off.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the scenario, but counting docs that have a certain tag is being done by that aggregation that you posted. Maybe post some tests, sample data and explain better what doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreiStefan edited to add some results / examples

Comment: You should specify a `size` in your aggregation, by default you only see the top ten tags. Since you have 345 matching documents, odds are high that the document you're showing doesn't contain one of the top ten tags.

Comment: But to be 100% sure, the aggregation is done on the result. Not the whole index?

Comment: Yes, only on the matching documents. And you can see in your response `"sum_other_doc_count": 3034`, which means that you have other available tags that are not shown in the aggregation response

Comment: is there an option to aggregate to only a "set of tags" ? and count on matching documents?

Comment: You can definitely add a `terms` filter in your query with the list of tags you want to consider... or if you don't want to restrict the results, but only the aggregations, you can add the tags `terms` array in a `filter` aggregation.

Comment: Great help! Thank you!